# How to access the next sibling of an xml tag in openxml sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xquery, sql-openxml

So i have an XML file which looks like below

```
declare @xml
xml= '<ENVELOPE>
    <BILLFIXED>
        <BILLDATE>29-Jun-2019</BILLDATE>
        <BILLREF>123</BILLREF>
        <BILLPARTY>ABC</BILLPARTY>
    </BILLFIXED>
    <BILLOP>200</BILLOP>
    <BILLCL>200</BILLCL>
    <BILLDUE>29-Jun-2019</BILLDUE>
    <BILLOVERDUE>1116</BILLOVERDUE>
    <BILLFIXED>
        <BILLDATE>30-Jun-2019</BILLDATE>
        <BILLREF>April To June -19</BILLREF>
        <BILLPARTY>efg</BILLPARTY>
    </BILLFIXED>
    <BILLOP>100</BILLOP>
    <BILLCL>100</BILLCL>
    <BILLDUE>30-Jun-2019</BILLDUE>
    <BILLOVERDUE>1115</BILLOVERDUE>
</ENVELOPE>
```

Im trying to read this using openxml

```
DECLARE  @hDoc AS INT, @SQL NVARCHAR (MAX) 

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @XML 

select   BILLDATE, BILLREF, BILLPARTY, BILLOP,BILLCL,BILLDUE, BILLOVERDUE
from OPENXML(@hDoc, '//BILLFIXED') 
WITH  
( 
BillDate [varchar](50) 'BILLDATE', 
BIllREF [varchar](50) 'BILLREF', 
BILLPARTY [varchar](100) 'BILLPARTY' 
,BILLOP [varchar](100) 'BILLOP' 
 BILLCL[varchar](100) 'REFERENCE', 
 BILLDUE [varchar](100) 'BILLDUE', 
 BILLOVERDUE [varchar](100) 'BILLOVERDUE'
)
```

It was easy to extract `<BILLFIXED>` tag but not able to access the siblings tags

```
<BILLCL>
<BILLDUE>
<BILLOVERDUE>
```

any help in accessing these tags
Thanks

Comment: Try `//BILLFIXED | //BILLFIXED/following-sibling::*[name()='BILLCL' or name()='BILLDUE' or name()='BILLOVERDUE']`

Comment: Tried this, it doesnt work error shows invalid axes name at following sibling

Comment: OK, then try `//BILLFIXED/../*[name()='BILLCL' or name()='BILLDUE' or name()='BILLOVERDUE']` or ``//*[name()='BILLCL' or name()='BILLDUE' or name()='BILLOVERDUE']``

Comment: So i tried this `//BILLFIXED/../*[name()='BILLCL']` but it shows the value of the first tag for all the rows

Comment: Pivot xml elements grouped by the number of previous BILLFIXED nodes `select 
  max(case when col = 'BILLDATE' then val end) as BILLDATE,
  max(case when col = 'BILLREF' then val end) as BILLREF,
  max(case when col = 'BILLPARTY' then val end) as BILLPARTY,
  max(case when col = 'BILLOP' then val end) as BILLOP,
  max(case when col = 'BILLCL' then val end) as BILLCL,
  max(case when col = 'BILLDUE' then val end) as BILLPARTY,
  max(case when col = 'BILLOVERDUE' then val end) as BILLOVERDUE`

Comment: `from (select b.b.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(200)') as col, b.b.value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(200)') as val,
sum(case when b.b.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(200)') = 'BILLFIXED' then 1 else 0 end) over(order by b.b rows unbounded preceding) as grp
from @xml.nodes('/ENVELOPE//*') as b(b)
) as x
group by grp`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree you should not use `OPENXML`, and instead use `.nodes` and `.value`.

Unfortunately, SQL Server does not allow the `sibling::` axis in XQuery, which would have made this much easier.

You can do this purely using XQuery, by using the `>>` positional predicate.

```sql
SELECT
      c.value('(BILLDATE /text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS BILLDATE
    , c.value('(BILLREF  /text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS BILLREF
    , c.value('(BILLPARTY/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS BILLPARTY
    , c.value('let $i := . return (/ENVELOPE/BILLOP     [. >> $i]/text())[1]', 'INT') AS BILLOP
    , c.value('let $i := . return (/ENVELOPE/BILLCL     [. >> $i]/text())[1]', 'INT') AS BILLCL
    , c.value('let $i := . return (/ENVELOPE/BILLDUE    [. >> $i]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS BILLDUE
    , c.value('let $i := . return (/ENVELOPE/BILLOVERDUE[. >> $i]/text())[1]', 'INT') AS BILLOVERDUE
FROM @xml.nodes('/ENVELOPE/BILLFIXED') AS t(c);
```

What this does is as follows:

- Shred just the `/ENVELOPE/BILLFIXED` nodes.
- For each of those, return the children as normal.
- For each sibling, do the following steps:

  - Store the current node in `$i`.
  - Take the first child node matching the correct name, of the parent,...
  - ...where that node is positioned after `$i`, so `[. >> $i]`
  - Take the first child node's text `[1]`

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d09d321f35bc20c5457628b3c2547f23)

If some of the nodes could be empty or missing, then you also need to check that the sibling node is before the next `BILLFIXED` node

```sql
SELECT
      c.value('(BILLDATE /text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS BILLDATE
    , c.value('(BILLREF  /text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS BILLREF
    , c.value('(BILLPARTY/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS BILLPARTY
    , c.value('let $i := . let $nxt := (/ENVELOPE/BILLFIXED[. >> $i])[1] return (/ENVELOPE/BILLOP     [. >> $i][. << $nxt]/text())[1]', 'INT') AS BILLOP
    , c.value('let $i := . let $nxt := (/ENVELOPE/BILLFIXED[. >> $i])[1] return (/ENVELOPE/BILLCL     [. >> $i][. << $nxt]/text())[1]', 'INT') AS BILLCL
    , c.value('let $i := . let $nxt := (/ENVELOPE/BILLFIXED[. >> $i])[1] return (/ENVELOPE/BILLDUE    [. >> $i][. << $nxt]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS BILLDUE
    , c.value('let $i := . let $nxt := (/ENVELOPE/BILLFIXED[. >> $i])[1] return (/ENVELOPE/BILLOVERDUE[. >> $i][. << $nxt]/text())[1]', 'INT') AS BILLOVERDUE
FROM @xml.nodes('/ENVELOPE/BILLFIXED') AS t(c);
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=eb22d9078a34554ab9e9965ac96a436c)

---

One final option is to transform the XML into a more normalized structure, and then query that

```sql
SELECT
      f.value('(BILLDATE   /text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS BILLDATE
    , f.value('(BILLREF    /text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS BILLREF
    , f.value('(BILLPARTY  /text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS BILLPARTY
    , c.value('(BILLOP     /text())[1]', 'INT') AS BILLOP
    , c.value('(BILLCL     /text())[1]', 'INT') AS BILLCL
    , c.value('(BILLDUE    /text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS BILLDUE
    , c.value('(BILLOVERDUE/text())[1]', 'INT') AS BILLOVERDUE
FROM (VALUES(
  @xml.query('
    for $bf in /ENVELOPE/BILLFIXED
    let $nxt := (/ENVELOPE/BILLFIXED[. >> $bf])[1]
    return
      <ENVELOPE>
        {$bf}
        {
            if ($nxt) then
                /ENVELOPE/*[. >> $bf][. << $nxt]
            else
                /ENVELOPE/*[. >> $bf]
        }
      </ENVELOPE>
  ')
) ) v(transformed)
CROSS APPLY v.transformed.nodes('/ENVELOPE') AS t(c)
CROSS APPLY t.c.nodes('BILLFIXED') t2(f);
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=63a417412ff93d774fd7974bcc3e2840)

Steps are as follows:

- Use `.query` to create a new XML document.
- For each `BILLFIXED` node, store that in `$bf`
- Store the `BILLFIXED` node which follows `$bf` in `$nxt`
- Return an `ENVELOPE` node, containing `$bf` as well as all nodes which...

  - ... are after `$bf`
  - ... and before `$nxt` if there is a `$nxt`
- Query that result as normal, using `.nodes`

Comment: appreaciate your answer & explanation 
+ its faster

Comment: Can you share any documentation or reference link that might help me to learn more about xquery?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/xquery-language-reference-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16 is a good start. I'm curious how much this option https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1fe43bcfe99baab793583973ad0131d3 takes compared to mine and Yitzhak's versions

Comment: If any of BILLOP,BILLCL,BILLDUE,BILLOVERDUE is empty then the results might get skewed https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c1c904e7f17d20321d4a4c786284954a

Comment: True, you could fix that by comparing also to the next `BILLFIXED` node https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=eb22d9078a34554ab9e9965ac96a436c

Comment: The `not($nxt)` in the xpath filter  is evaluated for every node and it hurts performance..one option would be to place the check in an if() to conditionally return the nodes after BILLFIXED.. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=faeaff33e8ff86d7d622f4653577f78c

Comment: Great answer, +1 from my side!

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft proprietary `OPENXML()` and its companions `sp_xml_preparedocument` and `sp_xml_removedocument` are kept just for backward compatibility with the obsolete SQL
Server 2000. Their use is diminished just to very few fringe cases.
Starting from SQL Server 2005 onwards, it is strongly recommended to re-write your SQL and switch it to XQuery.
Also, `OPENXML()` cannot take advantage of XML indexes while XQuery methods can.

Please try the following solution.

The XML sample is flattened.

So, we are using full power of XQuery.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @xml XML = 
N'<ENVELOPE>
    <BILLFIXED>
        <BILLDATE>29-Jun-2019</BILLDATE>
        <BILLREF>123</BILLREF>
        <BILLPARTY>ABC</BILLPARTY>
    </BILLFIXED>
    <BILLOP>200</BILLOP>
    <BILLCL>200</BILLCL>
    <BILLDUE>29-Jun-2019</BILLDUE>
    <BILLOVERDUE>1116</BILLOVERDUE>
    <BILLFIXED>
        <BILLDATE>30-Jun-2019</BILLDATE>
        <BILLREF>April To June -19</BILLREF>
        <BILLPARTY>efg</BILLPARTY>
    </BILLFIXED>
    <BILLOP>100</BILLOP>
    <BILLCL>100</BILLCL>
    <BILLDUE>30-Jun-2019</BILLDUE>
    <BILLOVERDUE>1115</BILLOVERDUE>
</ENVELOPE>';

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS Nmbr 
    , c.value('(./BILLDATE/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS BILLDATE
    , c.value('(./BILLREF/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS BILLREF
    , c.value('(./BILLPARTY/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS BILLPARTY
    , c.value('(/ENVELOPE/*[sql:column("seq.pos")]/text())[1]', 'INT') AS BILLOP
    , c.value('(/ENVELOPE/*[sql:column("seq.pos") + 1]/text())[1]', 'INT') AS BILLCL
    , c.value('(/ENVELOPE/*[sql:column("seq.pos") + 2]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS BILLDUE
    , c.value('(/ENVELOPE/*[sql:column("seq.pos") + 3]/text())[1]', 'INT') AS BILLOVERDUE
    , seq.pos   -- just to see
FROM @xml.nodes('/ENVELOPE/BILLFIXED') AS t(c)
   CROSS APPLY (SELECT t.c.value('let $n := . return count(/ENVELOPE/*[. << $n[1]]) + 2','INT') AS pos
         ) AS seq;
```

**Output**

| Nmbr | BILLDATE | BILLREF | BILLPARTY | BILLOP | BILLCL | BILLDUE | BILLOVERDUE | pos |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 29-Jun-2019 | 123 | ABC | 200 | 200 | 29-Jun-2019 | 1116 | 2 |
| 2 | 30-Jun-2019 | April To June -19 | efg | 100 | 100 | 30-Jun-2019 | 1115 | 7 |

Comment: It is possible to do this purely in XQuery without a cross-join, hard to say which is faster. You definitely don't need `*`, that's going to be slow. Just use the normal node names, for example https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1fe43bcfe99baab793583973ad0131d3

Comment: @Charlieface, followed you advice, and removed `*`. Thanks. By the way, Query cost relative to the batch shows 50% for both versions.

Comment: It would, the optimizer hasn't the faintest idea how much it actualy costs to query the XML. Need to time it properly

Comment: thanks for your suggestion & answer
Can u share any references or documentation with examples to understand xquery better?

Answer (score 1):

Pivot the xml elements grouped by the number of preceding BILLFIXED nodes, [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=581f8b51f8c4619a57a62a0e77ce7e1b).

```sql
declare @xml
xml= '<ENVELOPE>'+
replicate( cast('
    <BILLFIXED>
        <BILLDATE>29-Jun-2019</BILLDATE>
        <BILLREF>123</BILLREF>
        <BILLPARTY>ABC</BILLPARTY>
    </BILLFIXED>
    <BILLOP>200</BILLOP>
    <BILLCL>200</BILLCL>
    <BILLDUE>29-Jun-2019</BILLDUE>
    <BILLOVERDUE>1116</BILLOVERDUE>
    <BILLFIXED>
        <BILLDATE>30-Jun-2019</BILLDATE>
        <BILLREF>April To June -19</BILLREF>
        <BILLPARTY>efg</BILLPARTY>
    </BILLFIXED>
    <BILLOP>100</BILLOP>
    <BILLCL>100</BILLCL>
    <BILLDUE>30-Jun-2019</BILLDUE>
    <BILLOVERDUE>1115</BILLOVERDUE>' as nvarchar(max)), 100) +'
</ENVELOPE>';


select 
  max(case when col = 'BILLDATE' then val end) as BILLDATE,
  max(case when col = 'BILLREF' then val end) as BILLREF,
  max(case when col = 'BILLPARTY' then val end) as BILLPARTY,
  max(case when col = 'BILLOP' then val end) as BILLOP,
  max(case when col = 'BILLCL' then val end) as BILLCL,
  max(case when col = 'BILLDUE' then val end) as BILLPARTY,
  max(case when col = 'BILLOVERDUE' then val end) as BILLOVERDUE
from
(
select 
  b.b.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(200)') as col, b.b.value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(200)') as val,
  sum(case when b.b.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(200)') = 'BILLFIXED' then 1 else 0 end) 
  over(order by b.b rows unbounded preceding) as grp
from @xml.nodes('/ENVELOPE//*') as b(b)
) as x
group by grp;
```